# Greping folder names but exluding "@domain.com"

Tags: linux, scripting, grep

Is it possible to exclude a domain from a `grep`? What I have tried below doesn't seem to work.

```
ls -l /var/www/folder | grep -E -o --exclude-dir="@somedomain.com" --color "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b">>test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-l /var/www/folder | grep --invert-match "@somedomain.com" | grep -E -o --color "\b[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\b">>test.txt

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
ls -l /var/www/folder | grep -v "@somedomain.com"
```

test case:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/test && cd $_
$ touch {a,b,c,d}@domain.com
$ touch {e,f}@somedomain.com
$ ls
domain.com  b@domain.com  c@domain.com  d@domain.com  e@somedomain.com  f@somedomain.com
$ ls -1 | grep -v "@somedomain.com"
a@domain.com
b@domain.com
c@domain.com
d@domain.com
```

Here is what the man page says for `-v`

> ```
> -v, --invert-match
>          Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: I need to grep all other folders with an @otherdomain but not the ones with @domain.com so I thought exclude would work

Comment: I don't get how that's any different that the above, but anyway :)